multiple instances of TEMS Investigation on one windows server
I want to run multiple instances of TEMS Investigation app on a windows server simultaneously. In other words, different user are remotely connected to this server and each user wants to use the TEMS Investigation independently (each user be able to use one or more instances of TEMS). How can it be done?
Thanks in advance
